# how to trigger event when i type # or @ in textfeild in react/nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, draftjs

there I am building a new project and wondering how can i implement this in react/nextjs.
and i wanted show user selection or hashtag selction dialog around the textarea but didn't find any good article or github repo about it any one can help me that would be great!.

this is the video [link](https://res.cloudinary.com/appirathod/video/upload/v1663747102/Home___Twitter_-_Personal_-_Microsoft_Edge_2022-09-21_13-20-38_e1kigt.mp4).

Comment: This seems a pretty basic reactivity feature. You just have to watch the changes of a  textarea (onChange method), and do something if the input value contain #...

Comment: show us what you tried, but don't think stackoverflow will do the code for you..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <input
        type="text"
        onKeyUp={(e) => {
          console.log(e.key);
        }}
      />
```